# Class level locking - how efficient?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am a bit confused here when we have to use class level locking for synchronization of static variables using `synchronized(X.class)`.Here what I understand when a thread acquires a lock, no other thread will be able to access any other non-synchronized blocks as well which may incur a performance bottleneck. If there is a performance bottleneck what's the best way to deal with this problem.eg

```
class A {
    static int A = 0;

    public static synchorized func1() {
    }

    public synchorized func2() {
    }

    public synchorized func3() {
    }

    public synchorized func4() {
    }
}
```

In this case if a thread accesses `func1()`, no other thread will be able to access even other functions like `func2()`,`func3()`,`func4()`-if I am correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a question about class locking vs instance locking.

```
 public static synchronized test(){

 }    

 public synchronized test2(){

 }
```

These two methods are equivalent to:

```
 public static test(){
       synchronized(MyClass.class) {

       }
 }


 public static test2(){
       synchronized(this) {

       }
 }
```

They lock on different locks and thus `do not block each other`.

Your assumption that if a Thread calls `func1`; no other Thread can call `func2` and so-on is wrong, since they do use different locks.

On the other hand (considering we are talking about the same instance being called upon) if `ThreadA` calls `func2`, then another `ThreadB` can not call `func3` until `ThreadA` is done. This does not mean that it will **for sure** get the lock next - since there might be other threads waiting for that lock - and which one gets it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Perfect that solved my question.Thanks..!